# Using a dictionary of lambda functions in pandas.assign() gives the wrong result. How to avoid the lazy binding?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I would like to modify multiple columns with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
df = df.assign(**{v: lambda x:x[v]*10 for v in ['a', 'b']})
```

doesn't return the expected result.

```
10 30
20 40
```

It returns

```
30 30
40 40
```

To my understanding this is due to lazy binding, explained here: https://sopython.com/wiki/Common_Gotchas_In_Python

The desired result can be obtained by a proper function.

```
def fun(x):
    return x*10

df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].apply(fun)
```

Is there a way to break the lazy binding in a dictionary comprehension like above? Or are lambda functions too limited ?

Comment: Have you tried: `df.assign(**{v: lambda x,v=v:x[v]*10 for v in ['a', 'b']})` ? (note the `v=v`)

Comment: Which I think the lazy binding example on sopython does show - but I might think about updating it if that example isn't that clear...

Comment: Given your example though... you'd be better of using `df *= 10`...

Comment: @JonClements First comment is the acceptable answer for me. (I'll missed the idea on using two vars in a lambda on skimming through sopython's code).
Background: Agreed, df *= 10 is even shorter. I ran into this issue whilst refactoring a data cleansing pipeline and isolated it to the above toy example.

Comment: yeah... probably a dupe then... if you've any suggestions as to how to improve the page on sopython that'd make it clearer - I'd be happy to make edits (I'm a co-founder of the site :p)

Comment: @JonClements: should your first comment be elevated to an answer for this question? This helped me resolve a very frustrating issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @jon-clements correct comment:

```py
df.assign(**{v: lambda x,v=v:x[v]*10 for v in ['a', 'b']}) ?
```

Explained in a answer in the topic [How does python dict comprehension work with lambda functions inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862804/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the current dataframe the iterable of the dictionary comprehension if you stick it in .pipe():

```
df.pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(**{col: df_[col]*10 for col in df_}))
```

or:

```
df.pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(**{col: ser*10 for col, ser in df_.items()}))
```

That avoids the lazy binding issue but it's also helpful when you don't know the names of the columns, perhaps because it's part of a longer method chain.

Answer (score 0):

Something I would prefer (because it is more explicit and less prone to gotchas) is using the `df.items()` method:

```py
>>> df.assign(**{k: v * 10 for k, v in df.items() if k in {'a', 'b'}})
    a   b
0  10  30
1  20  40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df = df.assign(**{v: lambda x, col=v: x[col] * 10 for v in ['a', 'b']})

print(df)
```

Output

> ```
> a   b
> 0  10  30 
> 1  20  40
> ```